# How to remove add a line in the notebook of a many2many field? odoo 12

Tags: odoo

Actually i created a many2many field and add that in the field in a notebook.i've tried giving the options="{'no_create': True,'no_create_edit':True}" in the xml file.But the add a line button is still showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove the `add line` button/link on `one2many` or `many2many` list views you have to add `create="0"` to the tree node, for example:

```xml
<field name="my_x2many_field">
    <tree create="0">
        <field name="my_field" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: This blocks adding a line, but the add button is still visible. Is there a way to remove it completely ?

Comment: The add button shouldn't be visible. But maybe in some newer Odoo versions this won't work anymore.